# How to install and run this extension on ckan

Tags: ckan

How can I install and run the following extension in my ckan instance:

https://github.com/mxabierto/ckanext-dgm

They dont have any specific instructions/commands to run in the terminal and put this extension to use.

Plus there is no exact name mentioned to add to the ckan.plugins variable in the ckan config file.

Answer (score 0):

Install the extension using pip install https://github.com/mxabierto/ckanext-dgm.git and add it in your ini file (plugins = dgm). Also run ./bin/build-combined-ckan-mo.sh. as specified in docs to set up i18n